# Winforms Controls Flickering Despite Not Being Updated

Tags: c#, winforms

I've got a **very** long running task running asynchronously in the background of my program.

Whilst it is doing this, there are various events that take care of updating the GUI, utilising a `MethodInvoker` to ensure that these GUI updates are always run on the main thread.

However, dispite only the `ToolStripProgressBar` and the `ToolStripLabel` being changed, it appears as though two `ListBox`s on my form are being frequently redrawn as well causing them to flicker.

[image: Flickering controls]

Any idea why this is happening? I don't utilise `Update()` anywhere in my form so there's no reason that I'm aware of as to why non-invalidated controls would flicker.

I have also verified that the event which updates the `ListBox`s is not being fired by mistake.

The `EventHandler` for the progress step is set to the following function:

```
    private void UpdateProgress()
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke((MethodInvoker) UpdateProgress);
            return;
        }
        _lblProgress.Text = $"{_currentRow}/{_totalRows}";
        _pbarProgress.Increment(1);
    }
```

It's fairly self explanatory, if it needs to be `Invoked` then it does so before updating the `toolStripStatusLabel` and the `toolStripProgressBar`.

The entire layout has been generated and is handled by the `WinForms` designer but here's the code for that:

```
namespace Stability_Report_Generator
{
   partial class MainForm
   {
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this._tableLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
        this._lstMontrose = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
        this._lstBLP = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
        this._tableLayoutPanel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
        this._groupBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this._rdoAllData = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
        this._rdoLastShift = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
        this._rdoLastDay = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
        this._tableLayoutPanel3 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
        this._btnGenerate = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this._btnView = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this._btnClear = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this._label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this._label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this._statusStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip();
        this._lblStatus = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel();
        this._lblProgress = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel();
        this._pbarProgress = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripProgressBar();
        this._menuStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip();
        this._fileToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this._addFilesToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this._bLpsoeToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this._montroseSOEToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this._editToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this._removeFilesToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this._bLpOnlyToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this._montroseOnlyToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this._preferencesToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this._toolsToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this._viewGraphsToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this._tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
        this._tableLayoutPanel2.SuspendLayout();
        this._groupBox1.SuspendLayout();
        this._tableLayoutPanel3.SuspendLayout();
        this._statusStrip1.SuspendLayout();
        this._menuStrip1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // _tableLayoutPanel1
        // 
        this._tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 3;
        this._tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 33.33333F));
        this._tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 33.33334F));
        this._tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 33.33334F));
        this._tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this._lstMontrose, 0, 1);
        this._tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this._lstBLP, 1, 1);
        this._tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this._tableLayoutPanel2, 2, 1);
        this._tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this._label1, 0, 0);
        this._tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this._label2, 1, 0);
        this._tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this._statusStrip1, 2, 2);
        this._tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this._tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 84);
        this._tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "_tableLayoutPanel1";
        this._tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 3;
        this._tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 20F));
        this._tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
        this._tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 20F));
        this._tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1090, 420);
        this._tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // _lstMontrose
        // 
        this._lstMontrose.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this._lstMontrose.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this._lstMontrose.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 23);
        this._lstMontrose.Name = "_lstMontrose";
        this._lstMontrose.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(357, 374);
        this._lstMontrose.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // _lstBLP
        // 
        this._lstBLP.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this._lstBLP.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this._lstBLP.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(366, 23);
        this._lstBLP.Name = "_lstBLP";
        this._lstBLP.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(357, 374);
        this._lstBLP.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // _tableLayoutPanel2
        // 
        this._tableLayoutPanel2.ColumnCount = 1;
        this._tableLayoutPanel2.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
        this._tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this._groupBox1, 0, 1);
        this._tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this._tableLayoutPanel3, 0, 0);
        this._tableLayoutPanel2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this._tableLayoutPanel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(729, 23);
        this._tableLayoutPanel2.Name = "_tableLayoutPanel2";
        this._tableLayoutPanel2.RowCount = 2;
        this._tableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
        this._tableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
        this._tableLayoutPanel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(358, 374);
        this._tableLayoutPanel2.TabIndex = 2;
        // 
        // _groupBox1
        // 
        this._groupBox1.Controls.Add(this._rdoAllData);
        this._groupBox1.Controls.Add(this._rdoLastShift);
        this._groupBox1.Controls.Add(this._rdoLastDay);
        this._groupBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this._groupBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 190);
        this._groupBox1.Name = "_groupBox1";
        this._groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(352, 181);
        this._groupBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this._groupBox1.TabStop = false;
        this._groupBox1.Text = "Time Period";
        // 
        // _rdoAllData
        // 
        this._rdoAllData.AutoSize = true;
        this._rdoAllData.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 68);
        this._rdoAllData.Name = "_rdoAllData";
        this._rdoAllData.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(62, 17);
        this._rdoAllData.TabIndex = 2;
        this._rdoAllData.TabStop = true;
        this._rdoAllData.Text = "All Data";
        this._rdoAllData.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // _rdoLastShift
        // 
        this._rdoLastShift.AutoSize = true;
        this._rdoLastShift.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 44);
        this._rdoLastShift.Name = "_rdoLastShift";
        this._rdoLastShift.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(69, 17);
        this._rdoLastShift.TabIndex = 1;
        this._rdoLastShift.TabStop = true;
        this._rdoLastShift.Text = "Last Shift";
        this._rdoLastShift.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // _rdoLastDay
        // 
        this._rdoLastDay.AutoSize = true;
        this._rdoLastDay.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 20);
        this._rdoLastDay.Name = "_rdoLastDay";
        this._rdoLastDay.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(67, 17);
        this._rdoLastDay.TabIndex = 0;
        this._rdoLastDay.TabStop = true;
        this._rdoLastDay.Text = "Last Day";
        this._rdoLastDay.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // _tableLayoutPanel3
        // 
        this._tableLayoutPanel3.ColumnCount = 1;
        this._tableLayoutPanel3.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
        this._tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(this._btnGenerate, 0, 0);
        this._tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(this._btnView, 0, 1);
        this._tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(this._btnClear, 0, 2);
        this._tableLayoutPanel3.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this._tableLayoutPanel3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
        this._tableLayoutPanel3.Name = "_tableLayoutPanel3";
        this._tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount = 3;
        this._tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 33.33333F));
        this._tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 33.33333F));
        this._tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 33.33333F));
        this._tableLayoutPanel3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(352, 181);
        this._tableLayoutPanel3.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // _btnGenerate
        // 
        this._btnGenerate.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this._btnGenerate.Enabled = false;
        this._btnGenerate.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
        this._btnGenerate.Name = "_btnGenerate";
        this._btnGenerate.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(346, 54);
        this._btnGenerate.TabIndex = 0;
        this._btnGenerate.Text = "Generate Report";
        this._btnGenerate.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this._btnGenerate.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnGenerate_Click);
        // 
        // _btnView
        // 
        this._btnView.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this._btnView.Enabled = false;
        this._btnView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 63);
        this._btnView.Name = "_btnView";
        this._btnView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(346, 54);
        this._btnView.TabIndex = 1;
        this._btnView.Text = "View Details";
        this._btnView.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // _btnClear
        // 
        this._btnClear.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this._btnClear.Enabled = false;
        this._btnClear.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 123);
        this._btnClear.Name = "_btnClear";
        this._btnClear.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(346, 55);
        this._btnClear.TabIndex = 2;
        this._btnClear.Text = "Reset";
        this._btnClear.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // _label1
        // 
        this._label1.AutoSize = true;
        this._label1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this._label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 0);
        this._label1.Name = "_label1";
        this._label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(357, 20);
        this._label1.TabIndex = 3;
        this._label1.Text = "Montrose SOE Files";
        // 
        // _label2
        // 
        this._label2.AutoSize = true;
        this._label2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this._label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(366, 0);
        this._label2.Name = "_label2";
        this._label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(357, 20);
        this._label2.TabIndex = 4;
        this._label2.Text = "BLP SOE Files";
        // 
        // _statusStrip1
        // 
        this._statusStrip1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this._statusStrip1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this._statusStrip1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.None;
        this._statusStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
        this._lblStatus,
        this._lblProgress,
        this._pbarProgress});
        this._statusStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(936, 400);
        this._statusStrip1.Name = "_statusStrip1";
        this._statusStrip1.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
        this._statusStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(154, 20);
        this._statusStrip1.SizingGrip = false;
        this._statusStrip1.Stretch = false;
        this._statusStrip1.TabIndex = 5;
        this._statusStrip1.Text = "statusStrip1";
        // 
        // _lblStatus
        // 
        this._lblStatus.Name = "_lblStatus";
        this._lblStatus.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 15);
        this._lblStatus.Text = "Idle...";
        // 
        // _lblProgress
        // 
        this._lblProgress.Name = "_lblProgress";
        this._lblProgress.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 15);
        // 
        // _pbarProgress
        // 
        this._pbarProgress.Name = "_pbarProgress";
        this._pbarProgress.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 14);
        // 
        // _menuStrip1
        // 
        this._menuStrip1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this._menuStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
        this._fileToolStripMenuItem,
        this._editToolStripMenuItem,
        this._toolsToolStripMenuItem});
        this._menuStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 60);
        this._menuStrip1.Name = "_menuStrip1";
        this._menuStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1090, 24);
        this._menuStrip1.TabIndex = 1;
        this._menuStrip1.Text = "menuStrip1";
        // 
        // _fileToolStripMenuItem
        // 
        this._fileToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
        this._addFilesToolStripMenuItem});
        this._fileToolStripMenuItem.Name = "_fileToolStripMenuItem";
        this._fileToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(37, 20);
        this._fileToolStripMenuItem.Text = "File";
        // 
        // _addFilesToolStripMenuItem
        // 
        this._addFilesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
        this._bLpsoeToolStripMenuItem,
        this._montroseSOEToolStripMenuItem});
        this._addFilesToolStripMenuItem.Name = "_addFilesToolStripMenuItem";
        this._addFilesToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(122, 22);
        this._addFilesToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Add Files";
        // 
        // _bLpsoeToolStripMenuItem
        // 
        this._bLpsoeToolStripMenuItem.Name = "_bLpsoeToolStripMenuItem";
        this._bLpsoeToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(149, 22);
        this._bLpsoeToolStripMenuItem.Text = "BLP SOE";
        // 
        // _montroseSOEToolStripMenuItem
        // 
        this._montroseSOEToolStripMenuItem.Name = "_montroseSOEToolStripMenuItem";
        this._montroseSOEToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(149, 22);
        this._montroseSOEToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Montrose SOE";
        // 
        // _editToolStripMenuItem
        // 
        this._editToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
        this._removeFilesToolStripMenuItem,
        this._preferencesToolStripMenuItem});
        this._editToolStripMenuItem.Name = "_editToolStripMenuItem";
        this._editToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(39, 20);
        this._editToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Edit";
        // 
        // _removeFilesToolStripMenuItem
        // 
        this._removeFilesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
        this._bLpOnlyToolStripMenuItem,
        this._montroseOnlyToolStripMenuItem});
        this._removeFilesToolStripMenuItem.Name = "_removeFilesToolStripMenuItem";
        this._removeFilesToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(143, 22);
        this._removeFilesToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Remove Files";
        // 
        // _bLpOnlyToolStripMenuItem
        // 
        this._bLpOnlyToolStripMenuItem.Name = "_bLpOnlyToolStripMenuItem";
        this._bLpOnlyToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(153, 22);
        this._bLpOnlyToolStripMenuItem.Text = "BLP Only";
        // 
        // _montroseOnlyToolStripMenuItem
        // 
        this._montroseOnlyToolStripMenuItem.Name = "_montroseOnlyToolStripMenuItem";
        this._montroseOnlyToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(153, 22);
        this._montroseOnlyToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Montrose Only";
        // 
        // _preferencesToolStripMenuItem
        // 
        this._preferencesToolStripMenuItem.Name = "_preferencesToolStripMenuItem";
        this._preferencesToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(143, 22);
        this._preferencesToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Preferences";
        // 
        // _toolsToolStripMenuItem
        // 
        this._toolsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
        this._viewGraphsToolStripMenuItem});
        this._toolsToolStripMenuItem.Name = "_toolsToolStripMenuItem";
        this._toolsToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(48, 20);
        this._toolsToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Tools";
        // 
        // _viewGraphsToolStripMenuItem
        // 
        this._viewGraphsToolStripMenuItem.Name = "_viewGraphsToolStripMenuItem";
        this._viewGraphsToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(139, 22);
        this._viewGraphsToolStripMenuItem.Text = "View Graphs";
        // 
        // MainForm
        // 
        this.AllowDrop = true;
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1130, 524);
        this.Controls.Add(this._tableLayoutPanel1);
        this.Controls.Add(this._menuStrip1);
        this.MainMenuStrip = this._menuStrip1;
        this.Name = "MainForm";
        this.Text = "Stability Report Generator";
        this.DragDrop += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.MainForm_DragDrop);
        this.DragEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.MainForm_DragEnter);
        this._tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this._tableLayoutPanel1.PerformLayout();
        this._tableLayoutPanel2.ResumeLayout(false);
        this._groupBox1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this._groupBox1.PerformLayout();
        this._tableLayoutPanel3.ResumeLayout(false);
        this._statusStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this._statusStrip1.PerformLayout();
        this._menuStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this._menuStrip1.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel _tableLayoutPanel1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel _tableLayoutPanel2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox _groupBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton _rdoAllData;
    private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton _rdoLastShift;
    private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton _rdoLastDay;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel _tableLayoutPanel3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button _btnGenerate;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button _btnView;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button _btnClear;
    private System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip _menuStrip1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem _fileToolStripMenuItem;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem _addFilesToolStripMenuItem;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem _bLpsoeToolStripMenuItem;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem _montroseSOEToolStripMenuItem;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem _editToolStripMenuItem;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem _removeFilesToolStripMenuItem;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem _bLpOnlyToolStripMenuItem;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem _montroseOnlyToolStripMenuItem;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem _preferencesToolStripMenuItem;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem _toolsToolStripMenuItem;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem _viewGraphsToolStripMenuItem;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox _lstMontrose;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox _lstBLP;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label _label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label _label2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip _statusStrip1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel _lblStatus;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripProgressBar _pbarProgress;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel _lblProgress;
}
```

}

Comment: It looks like something appearing in the right listbox at some point? are you binding them to any data source?

Comment: The item in the right list box is there the whole time, the actual items don't change. It's just as the box is flickering it never seems to display properly. It's part of the `listbox` being redrawn

Comment: If you use async/await, you don't need a MethodInvoker. Even better, use Progress<T> to *decouple* whatever is publishing the progress message from the actual display. `Progress<T>` can support any type as a message, so you can publish the actual current row and totals without resorting to fields

Comment: In any case, the invoker has nothing to do with "flickering". It looks like either the toolstript doesn't cover the entire bottom, or the listboxes are resizing. For example, are you chaning the Z-order instead of docking to the bottom? You'd need to post your layout code for this. It's *very* hard to reproduce what you describe without a minimal example

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'll do some research on `Progress<T>`, in the meantime however, I have attached the layout code you asked for

Comment: @JamesHughes the status strip isn't docked or anchored to the bottom, which means that any changes that affect the size of the table panel rows, affect it as well

Comment: I've just tried docking the status strip control to the bottom of the tblLayoutPanel Cell and that hasn't helped. The size of the top and bottom rows is fixed so shouldn't be able to change?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing the flickering is the side effect of the [`ListBox.IntegralHeight`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.integralheight(v=vs.110).aspx) being `true` by default which is triggering the resizing algorithm which is changing the size of the control based on the content and it is apparently causing side effects.

---

The issue is observed when you update progress bar faster than once every 100 ms. Updates faster then that are causing the flickering right away, perhaps it has something to do with the internal implementation of the rendering loop for the progress bar control which is calling `SendMessage(NativeMethods.PBM_SETPOS, value, 0)` or internals of the window message loop itself and the way rendering is implemented behind the scene, hard to say.

You have an option to either slow down the updating of the progress bar by separating the progress bar increment from the `_currentRow` increment e.g. by putting the progress bar increment in some other timer tick handler triggered every 100 ms or even slower.

Or setting the `IntegralHeight` property to `false`, see below.

```
this._lstMontrose.IntegralHeight = false;
this._lstBLP.IntegralHeight = false;
```

Hope it is solving your issue!

Comment: I'll test this when I get to work tomorrow and get back to you, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new custom control, inheriting from the standard listbox, then in the constructor turn on DoubleBuffered:

```
public class CustomListBox : ListBox
{
  public CustomListBox() : base()
  { 
    base.DoubleBuffered = true;
  }
}
```

Change the type of the two Listboxes on your form to the new ListBox class.

This may help with the flickering re-draw issue.

Comment: Seems like overkill, although it should work so thanks, I would've thought that the fact that the `ListBox` is being redrawn in the first place was the problem?

Comment: Agreed, I don't think this is a complete solution to your problem, but it might help

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
private void UpdateProgress()
{
    _lblProgress.BeginInvoke((Action) (() =>
      {
        _lblProgress.Text = string.Format("{0}/{1}", _currentRow, _totalRows)
        _pbarProgress.Increment(1);
      });
}
```

Comment: There is no `BeginInvoke` method on `_lblProgress` I'm afraid

Comment: There should be... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It's not a `label`, it's a `toolStripStatusLabel`, I'll edit my question to make that more clear